# Hadoop map reduce example stuck on Running job

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, mapreduce, jobs

I am trying to run a mapreduce example in hadoop. I am using version 2.7.2. I tried running

`bin/hadoop jar libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`

and the mapreduce stuck at running job and does not advance any further.

it shows

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: What does the YARN UI and JobTracker tell you?

Answer (score 1):

I got it guys. It as the space problem. My HDD is 500 GB capacity. The used space should not exceed 90%. In my case there was only 30GB left. I cleaned up some spce by deleting Apps and Files. Its running Good.